# Pandas memory usage gives weird estimates

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, memory

Pandas gives very strange memory estimates. It can't be that a column with lists of **2 numbers**, takes almost the same memory as a column with **100 numbers**. Numpy's `nbytes` makes more sense (see example below), but doesn't the `memory_usage` with `deep=True` knows how to deal with it?

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np

    n_rows = 100000
    vecs_1x2 = np.random.random((n_rows, 2))
    mats_10x10 = np.random.random((n_rows, 10, 10))
    df = pd.DataFrame({'vecs_1x2': list(vecs_1x2), 'mats_10x10': list(mats_10x10)})

    print('numpy - vecs_1x2.nbytes: {} Mb'.format(vecs_1x2.nbytes / 1024.**2))
    print('numpy - mats_10x10.nbytes: {} Mb'.format(mats_10x10.nbytes / 1024.**2))
    print('pandas - df.memory_usage (in Mb):\n{}'.format(df.memory_usage(deep=True, index=False) / 1024.**2))
```

Outputs:

```
    numpy - vecs_1x2.nbytes: 1.52587890625 Mb
    numpy - mats_10x10.nbytes: 76.2939453125 Mb
    pandas - df.memory_usage (in Mb):
    mats_10x10    11.444092
    vecs_1x2       9.918213
```

How?!

Comment: The estimates are fine on columns of type string, int, float, boolean, category, datetime et al.; it's only on 'object' (arbitary Python or foreign object) they can't introspect accurately. In fairness you're inserting numpy array objects into a dataframe, which is not something a typical pandas user would do. At best this is an enhance case for `df.memory_usage(deep=True)` to warn "'object': memory-usage is only an estimate". Or you can hack up an estimator for type 'object' which tries to access the np `. nbytes` accessor if it exists, else falls back on `sys.getsizeof()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's going on is that you are creating columns with dtype of object. Basically, it's storing a NumPy array of Python objects.

So what you get is a NumPy array of pointers, basically. If you choose the deep option it tries to get individual items memory usage too, using `sys.getsizeof()` I suspect.

So `deep=True` is "size of the array, plus whatever guess is at object size":

```
>>> sys.getsizeof(df.vecs_1x2.iloc[0]) * n_rows + df.vecs_1x2.memory_usage(deep=False)
11200128
>>> df.vecs_1x2.memory_usage(deep=True)
11200128
```

Now, `sys.getsizeof()` will add the Python object overhead:

```
>>> sys.getsizeof(df.vecs_1x2.iloc[0])
104
>>> df.vecs_1x2.iloc[0].nbytes
16
```

But `sys.getsizeof()` doesn't know how much memory the object stores internally, necessarily, given arbitrary extension types:

```
>>> sys.getsizeof(df.mats_10x10.iloc[0])
120
>>> df.mats_10x10.iloc[0].nbytes
800
>>> sys.getsizeof(df.mats_10x10.iloc[0]) * n_rows + df.mats_10x10.memory_usage(deep=False)
12800128
>>> df.mats_10x10.memory_usage(deep=True)
12800128
```

**TL;DR:** For object dtypes, `memory_usage()` is not helpful.

So how do you measure memory usage?

One option is a memory profiler. For example, I work on the [Fil memory profiler for Python](https://pythonspeed.com/fil) which specifically is designed for data science and scientific computing. It will tell you peak memory usage and which lines of code were responsible.

[Another profiler](https://pypi.org/project/memory-profiler/) can show you how much memory was allocated on each line of code, which can be useful for profiling little tiny snippets of code.

Comment: But you would expect pandas fellas to use `type`, and if they see that they have a numpy array type, use something like nbytes, no?